# after manually editing .vcproj (VS2008) file, source file list is gone

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv

I am in the process of getting some linux projects ported to visual studio 2008, using openCv and PvAPI (gigE camera driver), Allied Vision Tech (AVT) has samples for both Linux and Windows, of which I began using the Linux SDK. Now I'm trying to bring this over to Windows, and when I edit the .vcproj file for my solution to include fully-qualified paths to my include and lib files, the source file list disappears for no apparent reason. Is there some way to reconstruct/fix my project files?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you must provide relative paths in the project file.